# Clarification on the only if statement.

Tags: logic

Every time we solve questions of the form "Find all the solutions $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ to the equation $$f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0",$$ we first assume that $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ is a solution to the given equation and then find out the value of $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ through known techniques.

But observe that this just means that "if $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0,$ then $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n).$"  But the question asks us to find all such $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ such that we can conclude that "$f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0$ only if $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$."

I understand that most of the times while such questions are asked, the questioner has already in mind that $$f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0\iff (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n).$$ From here, we can conclude that $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0$, only if or only when $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, hence we never care.

But there are times too, when after finding out a set of solutions $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, we verify if all of these solutions satisfy the equation $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0$ or not. Normally, if some solution does not satisfy the equation we eliminate that solution, and claim that the equation holds true only when $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ equals the remaining set of solutions.

Let me try to make my point clear with a more simpler example. Suppose that we need to solve some linear equation $f(x)=0$. We assume that $f(x)=0$ for some $x$ and find out that $x=a,b,c,d,e$. Therefore, we have if $f(x)=0$, then $x=a,b,c,d,e$. Now suppose that while checking we see that $f(b)\neq 0$ and $f(e)\neq 0$, but $f(a)=f(c)=f(d)=0$. This rightly means that if $x=a,c,d$, then $f(x)=0$. But, does it also mean that $f(x)=0$, only if $x=a,c,d$? Will no other value satisfy this equation other than $a,c,d$?

Surely, one way to prove only if statements is using "proof by contradiction". Like for the above example, let us assume that $\exists k$, which is distinct from $a,c,d$, such that $f(k)=0$. And assuming that, we can surely reach to some sort of contradiction.

Not only equations, while solving math problems, such situations keep arising in each and every field of Math, but no one seems to emphasize on this rigorous fact. I hope someone answers.

Comment: "Every time...through known techniques."  This isn't true.  A rigorous answer to such a question always demonstrates that all applicable solutions are captured in the given characterization.  In particular, this demands more than simple verification that a given form satisfies the stated condition.

Comment: It might be easier to assess any potential problems with such questions if you give an example of a question you find answered in an unsatisfactory manner.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to prove we have all solutions.  Which are effective depends on what the problem is.  If we are solving a set of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns, we can know that there is a unique solution unless the equations are redundant.  We can calculate the determinant of the coefficient matrix and find it is nonzero to prove there is only one solution.  As you say, sometimes the techniques we use to find the solution are reversible so the act of finding them is sufficient.  Sometimes we find a solution through guesswork, then prove it is a solution.  In the linear case we would be done.  In other cases we may need to prove there are no other solutions.  Sometimes we assume that some one of the variables is different from the solution we have and prove a contradiction.  I don't think there is much more to say in general.  It depends on the specific problem.